# Format timestamp in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm trying to `format my current time-stamp` into something like this: `2017_07_15_000000` I'm using `laravel` application and I can achieve `current time-stamp` through `Carbon::now`

Guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) - especially `format()` method.

```
<?php
$time = Carbon::now(); // for current timestamp
// OR:
// use with your own timestamp:
// $time = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($your_timestamp);

echo $time->format('Y_m_d_His'); // your desired format
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and pass date as per your requirement.
[Demo is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6b04e3a29e28ff973da42fe742e7457bd378e59)

```
<?php

$date = "01-01-2017 23:23:59";

echo date('Y_m_d_His',strtotime($date));

?>
```

Comment: No don't try it; when OP is using Carbon or DateTime objects, then telling them too revert to basic date/time functions is a regression